# how to set backbone fetch callback method

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

How do you set the jsonpCallback function name for the fetch method of backbonejs?   To add to the problem is I also using requireJS so i am trying not to have a global function and follow the AMD pattern.

The reason I can't use the auto generated method name from jquery is the developer of the api I am using want's to have a static name of for the callback method for caching reasons.

**Sample Code**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'paginator',
    'models/item'], function($, _, Backbone, Marionette, Paginator, modelItem) {
    'use strict';

        var PaginatedCollection = Paginator.requestPager.extend({ 
            model: modelItem,

            paginator_core: {
               jsonpCallback : 'callbackFunc',

                type: 'GET',
                cache: true,

                dataType: 'jsonp',

            },      
            callbackFunc : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }

        });

        return PaginatedCollection;

    });
```

**Error Message**

TypeError: callbackFunc is not a function

Comment: Can you show us your code? Is Jsonp support part of Backbone or of another library you are using?

Comment: [WhatHaveYouTried.com](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Added sample code.  Just showing the part that i am having problems with.

Comment: Does `callbackFunc` need to be global?

Comment: how do i do that with requireJs since everything is a module and not global

Comment: If it needs to be global then `window.callbackFunc=...`, else if the error is because `jsonpCallback` is passed as a string and not a function, then try `jsonpCallback : function(data) { console.log(data); }`.

Comment: @PaulGrime passing 'jsonpCallback' as function will cause jquery to create an random function name in ?callback.  passing it as string is in the docs of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Override your fetch to pass the callback method name in the request.

```
fetch: function(options) {
  options || (options = {});
  var data = (options.data || {});
  options.dataType = 'jsonp';
  options.jsonp = 'callbackFunc';

  return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to cache the results (in the browser, and maybe on the server as well) you also need to set `options.cache` param.

Also the param is `jsonpCallback` not `jsonp`

Here's what your sync over-ride function should look like:

```
sync: function (method, model, options) {
    options.timeout = 10000; // required, or the application won't pick up on 404 responses
    options.dataType = 'jsonp';
    options.jsonpCallback = 'callbackFunc';
    options.cache = 'true';
    return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
}
```

NB: BackboneJS v1.0, not tested in 0.9 or earlier