# jsonpCallback parseResponse is not a function with geoserver

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, geoserver

I am getting a 'parseResponse' is not a function when doing a request to a geoserver. I tried several things to get passed this problem, but the outcome remains: 'parseResponse is not a function'

I tried setting the sync options in the fetch,
I tried using cache: true,
I did override the sync

I did look into these possible solutions:
[how to set backbone fetch callback method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937812/how-to-set-backbone-fetch-callback-method)

[Caching jsonp callback parameter when doing a backbone fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981774/caching-jsonp-callback-parameter-when-doing-a-backbone-fetch)

here is the code:

```
var APP = APP || {};

APP.WaterDepthStatusModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: '',

    initialize: function (url) {
        this.url = url;
    },

    calcUrl: function (xy, mapInfo, RD, mapUrl, emptyInfo) {

        var mapWidth = mapInfo._size.x;
        var mapHeight = mapInfo._size.y;
        var boundsNE = RD.projection.project(mapInfo.getBounds().getNorthEast());
        var boundsSW = RD.projection.project(mapInfo.getBounds().getSouthWest());
        var BBOX = boundsSW.x + ',' + boundsSW.y + ',' + boundsNE.x + ',' + boundsNE.y;
        var zoom = mapInfo.getZoom();

        var buildUrl = mapUrl;
            buildUrl += '?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo';
            buildUrl += '&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml';
            buildUrl += '&INFO_FORMAT=text/javascript';
            buildUrl += '&format=image/png';
            buildUrl += '&QUERY_LAYERS=' + APP.servers.waterDepthStatus;
            buildUrl += '&Layers=' + APP.servers.waterDepthStatus;
            buildUrl += '&BBOX=' + BBOX;
            buildUrl += '&WIDTH=' + mapWidth;
            buildUrl += '&HEIGHT=' + mapHeight;
            buildUrl += '&x=' +  xy.x;
            buildUrl += '&y=' + xy.y;
            buildUrl += '&srs=EPSG:28992';

        this.url = buildUrl;

    },

    sync: function (method, model, options) {

        options.dataType = "jsonp";
        options.crossDomain = true;
        options.jsonpCallback = "parseResponse";
        options.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);

    }

});
```

this is the response I get from the server:

```
parseResponse({"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":1,"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"MEGO_overstromingNL_Status.1754","geometry":null,"properties":{"CODE":3}}]})
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what is in the returned response? is it a function?

Comment: is is in jsonp so response looks like: parseResponse({jsonhere});

Comment: we need to see the {jsonhere} bit then

Comment: See update, don't think it will do any good though...

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in this [question on gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57494/geoserver-2-3-how-to-enable-jsonp).

There are a number of possible issues:

1. You need to turn Jsonp on in the `web.xml` file.
2. You need to provide a function for the Json to callback to.
3. Make sure you use the `text/javascript` output format.